# Google Apps Script V8 runtime issue with throwException()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, v8, rhino

I am trying to migrate my current GSuite Add-on script project to V8 engine as per Google's recommendation. I got everything working except that whereever I use:

```
CardService
.newAuthorizationException()
.setCustomUiCallback('create3PAuthorizationUi')
.throwException();
```

Add-on is stopping with a runtime error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, provide us with the exact error message you get, then we will be able to take a look

Comment: Please, also share the ```create3PAuthorizationUi``` function just in case the error is coming from there.

Comment: Exception: Exception [line: 270, function: logout, file: Auth]

Comment: NO issues if I switch back to V5..Also getting same error in another place when I use another custom function..So, no issues in create3PAuthorizationUi..right?

Comment: Maybe it's throwing the exception, but failing to build the custom function UI mentioned as "setCustomUiCallback" in V8??

Comment: Hm, just to make sure - do you have a `logout` function - if not, this might be an internal issue, but if you do - please, provide the code of it

Comment: This seems to be a bug because it's working when you are using the V5, but if you change to V8 suddenly it doesn't work anymore. You can report your situation on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905), there you can fill the template in order to let them know you that bug exists.

Comment: @albertovielma - after digging in I am able to consistently reproduce OP's issue, seems like this is indeed a bug. I've [created an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/149832151), as it seems to be quite critical

Comment: For those having this issue, add your comments, stars and +1 to the [the public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/149832151) created by @OlegValter

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You are missing the **required** [`setAuthorizationUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/authorization-exception#setAuthorizationUrl(String)) method in the chain. I am not sure why switching back to Rhino runtime works for you, probably the error detection is improved.

Also, since we do not have the code for the `logout` function that causes the error, you might have another migration issue unrelated to authorization.

**Solution**

Your snippet should look something like this:

```
const authUrl = "https://example.com";

CardService
  .newAuthorizationException()
  .setAuthorizationUrl(authUrl)
  .setCustomUiCallback('create3PAuthorizationUi')
  .throwException();
```

**Issue Tracker note**

The issue I created on the issue tracker is now closed as intended behavior. Turns out the URI provided to the method (see `authUrl`) must be a valid URI. Technically, it accepts invalid and unreachable URIs, the only requirement is that the argument *must* be a string.

Because during testing I relied on the `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` method call chain on a *new project* not deployed as a Web App, therefore the `authUrl` held `null`.